# How to change timescale of VCD file dumped?

Tags: c++, fpga, chisel

I'm trying to use Chisel on a "real-world" project and I'm writing the testbench code part in C++.
That work well, I can see all my dumped signals in the dump.vcd file with gtkwave.

But I have a problem for timescale, by default, the function module->dump() record signal with timescale at 1ps:

```
$timescale 1ps $end
```

Do you know how to change it ?

The only way I found to change it in the testbench C++ code is to re-open the vcd after closing it and modify the first line :

```
#define CYCLE_PERIOD_NS   10
FILE *f = fopen("./dump.vcd", "w");
module->set_dumpfile(f);
[...]
/*several module->dump() call */
[...]
if (f) {
    fclose(f);

    std::string line;
    std::ifstream input("./dump.vcd");
    std::ofstream output("./tmp.vcd");
    std::getline(input, line);
    output << "$timescale " << CYCLE_PERIOD_NS << "ns $end" << endl;
    while(std::getline(input, line)) {
        output << line << endl;
    }
    rename("./tmp.vcd", "./dump.vcd");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I given work only for C++ backend, the problem remain the same if we use chisel class Test.
I modified Chisel code to add the **period** in implicitClock object. Then I modified the Vcd class to dump VCD with the correct period value. You can see the patch [here](https://github.com/Martoni/chisel/commit/7d6e0c19b4cb705e99e6fbd44416afec692f0b8fhttp://).

Then to change timescale you just have to add the following line in your top Chisel module:

```
class myModule extends Module {
[...]
Driver.implicitClock.period = "10ns"
[...]
}
```

This patch has been commited for the version 2.2.28 of Chisel.