# passing arguments to verilator backend in chisel

Tags: chisel, register-transfer-level

i have wrote a simple PeekPokeTester testbench in chisel and it compiles and run successfully using verilator backend.
but now i want to pass some flags to verilator backend. in driver options there is a "--more-vcs-flags" option but there is not a similar thing for verilator. is there any way to change verilator flags or CFLAGS? 
to be more specific i want to simulate xilinx primitives as blackbox in chisel and i have to add something like "-y $VIVADO_INSTALL_DIR/data/verilog/src/unisims" to verilator compilation command
thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue open for this subject on project : https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-testers/issues/148

Comment: Thanks but its about vcs and they have added options for vcs but there is no similar thing for verilator. Is theere any other way?

Comment: I asked a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638404/how-to-change-timescale-in-vcd-generated-by-chisel3-iotester . As I know, there is no solution for this moment.